# Grok filter for class name containing $

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I am facing issue while using the Grok filter. Below is my filter which is working as expected while the class name do not have `$` in it. When thread name is like **PropertiesReader$** it is failing. What else can I use so it can parse class name with special characters ?

```
filter {
      grok {  
           match => [ "message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:LogDate} %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{WORD:threadName}:%{NUMBER:ThreadID} - %{GREEDYDATA:Line}" ] 
      }
      json {
           source => "Line" 
      }
      mutate { 
            remove_field => [ "Line" ]  
      }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `WORD` as a pattern for your `threadname` which does not contain special characters. To confirm this let's take a look at this pattern: `WORD \b\w+\b`

Use a custom pattern. Just describe it in a file like this:

```
MYPATTERN ([A-z]+\$?)
```

Then you can use it in your config like this:

```
grok {
    patterns_dir => ["/path/to/pattern/dor"]
    match => [ "message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:LogDate} %LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{MYPATTERN:threadName}:%{NUMBER:ThreadID} - %GREEDYDATA:Line}" ] 
     }
```

You'll find more information about custom patterns in the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html)

Answer (score 3):

You aren't limited to `grok` pattern names.  You can do any regex.  For example in place of `%{WORD:threadName}` you can put `(?<threadName>[^:]+)` which says to match any character that isn't a `:` and assign it to `threadName`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try with `%{DATA:threadName}` instead of `%{WORD:threadName}`, if your threadName won't contain whitespaces or colons.